# How to build facebook login in admin on rest?

Tags: reactjs, admin-on-rest

```
     const responseFacebook = (response) => {
      console.log(response);
      const payload = {
        id: response.id,
        name: response.name,
        email: response.email,
        token: response.accessToken
      }
      return payload
    }

    class FacebookLogin extends Component {
        co
        login = (auth) => {
          console.log("************Entering***************** ")
          this.props.userLogin(auth, this.props.location.state ? this.props.location.state.nextPathname : '/')
        };

        render() {
            const { handleSubmit, submitting, theme } = this.props;
            const muiTheme = getMuiTheme(theme);
            const { primary1Color, accent1Color } = getColorsFromTheme(muiTheme);
            return (
                <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={muiTheme}>
                    <div style={{ ...styles.main, backgroundColor: primary1Color }}>
                        <Card style={styles.card}>
                            <div style={styles.avatar}>
                                <Avatar backgroundColor={accent1Color} icon={<LockIcon />} size={60} />
                            </div>
                            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.login)}>
                                <CardActions>
                                <FacebookLogin
                                    appId="1023727501002149"
                                    autoLoad={true}
                                    fields="name,email,picture"
                                    callback={responseFacebook}
                                    cssClass="my-facebook-button-class"
                                    icon="fa-facebook"
                                    />
                                </CardActions>
                            </form>
                        </Card>
                        <Notification />
                    </div>
                </MuiThemeProvider>
            );
        }
    }

    FacebookLogin.propTypes = {
        ...propTypes,
        authClient: PropTypes.func,
        previousRoute: PropTypes.string,
        theme: PropTypes.object,
        userLogin: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    };

    FacebookLogin.defaultProps = {
        theme: defaultTheme,
    };

    const enhance = compose(
        reduxForm({
            form: 'signIn',
            validate: (values, props) => {
                const errors = {};
                return errors;
            },
        }),
        connect(null, { userLogin: userLoginAction }),
    );

    export default enhance( FacebookLogin );
```

I am trying to implement facebook login in admin on rest  using https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-facebook-login.

This login component is getting me the response from facebook which i need to send to login function defined in the facebookLogin Class.

Please do advice how can I create custom facebook login page in admin on rest using react component

Help would be really appreciated

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 2):

```
    class EmailLogin extends Component {
        //function which gets the reponse from the
        responseFacebook = (response) => {
          const payload = {
            id: response.id,
            name: response.name,
            email: response.email,
            token: response.accessToken
          }
          this.props.userLogin(payload, this.props.location.state ? this.props.location.state.nextPathname : '/')
        };

        render() {
            const { handleSubmit, submitting, theme } = this.props;
            console.log("#### 1:", handleSubmit)
            console.log("#### 2:", submitting);
            const muiTheme = getMuiTheme(theme);
            const { primary1Color, accent1Color } = getColorsFromTheme(muiTheme);
            return (
                <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={muiTheme}>
                    <div style={{ ...styles.main, backgroundColor: primary1Color }}>
                        <Card style={styles.card}>
                            <div style={styles.avatar}>
                                <Avatar backgroundColor={accent1Color} icon={<LockIcon />} size={60} />
                            </div>
                            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.responseFacebook)}>
                                <CardActions>
                                <FacebookLogin
                                    type="submit"
                                    appId="1023727501002149"
                                    autoLoad={true}
                                    fields="name,email,picture"
                                    callback={this.responseFacebook}
                                    icon={<CircularProgress size={25} thickness={2} />}
                                    />
                                </CardActions>
                            </form>
                        </Card>
                        <Notification />
                    </div>
                </MuiThemeProvider>
            );
        }
    }

    EmailLogin.propTypes = {
        ...propTypes,
        authClient: PropTypes.func,
        previousRoute: PropTypes.string,
        theme: PropTypes.object,
        userLogin: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    };

    EmailLogin.defaultProps = {
        theme: defaultTheme,
    };

    const enhance = compose(
        reduxForm({
            form: 'signIn',
            validate: (values, props) => {
                const errors = {};
                return errors;
            },
        }),
        connect(null, { userLogin: userLoginAction }),
    );

    export default enhance( EmailLogin );
```

------UPDATED--------

The facebook react component has a callback param which calls a function name responseFacebbok

That function should be triggered at the time of form submit this will help to redirect the response to the authClient which finally calls the backend API.

Comment: Hi there. You should probably rename the component to something more appropriate.